# How to restore $form_state when rebuilding a form after a redirect

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, sessions

We have a site where either authenticated or unauthenticated users can submit a form. When the form is validated, we check whether they are logged-in, and if not, we redirect them to authenticate, with a destination parameter of the original page. At this point, we cache the `$form` and `$form_state` in `$_SESSION`.

After authentication and redirection the form is redisplayed on the page (by retrieving the `$form` from `$_SESSION`) and ask them to confirm the submit.
Note the form is dynamically-generated which is why we have to store it.

What I can't seem to do on redisplay is set the form values to the choices that the user previously made, even though these are stored in the cached `$form_state`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in the end. The solution was:

```
$form_array = drupal_retrieve_form($cached_form, $cached_form_state);
$form = $form_array['#form_id'];
$block['content'] = drupal_render($form);
```

where `$cached_form` and `$cached_form_state` were the `$form` and `$form_state` values that had been stored in `$_SESSION`. Note that `'#form_id'` is a literal string, I've no idea why `drupal_retrieve_form` returns an array with that string as a key.

This redisplayed the form in the block after the authentication challenge, with the user's pre-challenge selections populated into the form elements. I couldn't get it to work with either `drupal_get_form()` or `drupal_build_form()`.